# Laravel hasMany() + where() returns where conditions in opposite order

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Using the following:

```
return $this->hasMany(Text::class, 'item_id')->where('item_type', 'product');
```

Will make a query like this:

```
select * from `texts` where `item_type` = 'product' and `texts`.`item_id` in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10')
```

What I would like to have is:

```
select * from `texts` where `texts`.`item_id` in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10') and `item_type` = 'product'
```

So, how can I change the order of columns in where statement when using hasMany() + multiple where()s?

This is to get the most out of a composite index.

Comment: Assuming that you have already tried swapping hasMany() and where(), you could always go for a raw query. Obviously, there is no such thing as 'where' order

Comment: hasMany() has to be piped into $this. It can't be called from where() without an error.

Answer (score 2):

Since [Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html) has a public property of the array type called **`wheres`**, you can reverse it.

```
    $hasMany = $this->hasMany(Text::class, 'item_id')->where('item_type', 'product');
    $eloquentBuilder = $hasMany->getQuery();
    $queryBuilder = $eloquentBuilder->getQuery();
    $queryBuilder->wheres = array_reverse($queryBuilder->wheres);
    return $hasMany;
```

This will work, but I recommend you at least trying raw wheres.

See:

[Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereRaw()](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereRaw)

[Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::orWhereRaw()](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orWhereRaw)

I hope it helps.